# Menu block makes parent menu item active when maximum levels not cover the linked node

Tags: navigation

In Drupal 7, a menu block can specify maximum levels.
If the maximum levels is not enough to cover all menu items linked node, when in the
not-covered menu items linked node, could menu be active at their parent menu item?

For example,  a menu has 3 levels, and specify maximum levels = 2, when at level 3 menu 
item linked node, could open its parent menu item in level 2?

Have a menu like this:
M1
 M11
  M111
  M112 - link node PageM112
 M12
  M121
M2

If maximum levels = unlimites
At PageM112 node page, the menu will be like this.
M1
 M11
  M111
  M112 - linking to PageM112
 M12
M2

If maximum levels = 2, going to PageM112 node page, the menu will closed, like this.
M1
M2
M3

In this situation, could the menu be active at its parent menu item, M11, with the menu
expanded like this?
M1
 M11 - active 
 M12
M2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need the [Menu Position](https://drupal.org/project/menu_position) module. Using this module you can keep Parent Menu item active at any level of it's sub items.

> This module allows for the creation of rules that will dynamically add the current page into the menu system at the requested spots.